# Javascript not displaying responsive nav

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to make the Javascript show and hide responsive nav menu via hamburger click.

I did manage to get some sort of function but it toggled the actual navigation bar as a whole when I only want the ul links to hide/display.

I think I have the class names incorrect or with the wrong structure

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-menu')[0];
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('ul')[0];
console.log(toggleButton);
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('nav-menu')
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/01-digitall');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

nav .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  

}

.logo {
  font-family: '01 Digitall';
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo .black {
  color: #000000;
}

.logo .red {
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;


}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  
}

nav li {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

nav a {
  color: #000000;
}


@media (max-width: 1008px) {

nav {
  position: relative;
  
}
/*
.logo {
  
}*/

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 30px;
}

nav ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: #ecf0f1;

  


  
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

nav li {
padding-left: 0;
padding: 10px;

}

nav a {
  color: #000;
}

.navmenu.active {
display: flex;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navigation-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <span class="black">JS Test</span>
      </div>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="nav-menu">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

I am not very literate in JS.

Comment: Did you look at the error that's provided?

Comment: It means that the element on which you're calling `classList` doesn't exist. In this case, you have no elements with class `ul`.